# Is it possible to specify the `DispatchQueue` for `DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform`?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

[`dispatch_apply`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1453050-dispatch_apply) takes a dispatch queue as a parameter, which allows you to choose which queue to execute the block on.

My understanding is that `DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform` in Swift is meant to replace `dispatch_apply`. But this function does not take a dispatch queue as a parameter. After googling around, I found [this GCD tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5371-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-2-2) which has this code:

```
let _ = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: addresses.count) { index in
    // do work here
}
```

And explains:

> This implementation includes a curious line of code: `let _ = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)`. Calling this tells causes GCD to use a queue with a `.userInitiated` quality of service for the concurrent calls.

My question is, does this actually work to specify the QoS? If so, how?

It would kind of make sense to me that there is no way to specify the queue for this, because a serial queue makes no sense in this context and only the highest QoS really makes sense given that this is a synchronous blocking function. But I can't find any documentation as to why it is possible to specify a queue with `dispatch_apply` but impossible(?) with `DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The author’s attempt to specify the queue quality of service (QoS) is incorrect. The `concurrentPerform` uses the current queue’s QoS if it can. You can confirm this by tracking through the source code:

1. `concurrentPerform` calls [`_swift_dispatch_apply_current`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/6162a1d17948502cbe0576058d19e095ef3ad8c7/src/swift/Queue.swift#L115).
2. [`_swift_dispatch_apply_current`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/6e7051eb1e38e743a514555d09256d12d3fec750/stdlib/public/SwiftShims/DispatchOverlayShims.h#L194) calls `dispatch_apply` with `0`, i.e.,  `DISPATCH_APPLY_AUTO`, which is [defined as](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/9ec95bfbc2f15f38ea08d68b4cb37ccf5fe4007e/dispatch/queue.h#L220) a ...

   > ... Constant to pass to `dispatch_apply()` or `dispatch_apply_f()` to request that the system automatically use worker threads that match the configuration of the current thread as closely as possible.
   >
   > When submitting a block for parallel invocation, passing this constant as the queue argument will automatically use the global concurrent queue that matches the Quality of Service of the caller most closely.
3. This can also be confirmed by following `dispatch_apply` call `dispatch_apply_f` in which using `DISPATCH_APPLY_AUTO` results in the call to [`_dispatch_apply_root_queue`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/master/src/apply.c#L248). If you keep tumbling down the rabbit hole of [swift-corelibs-libdispatch](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch), you’ll see that this actually does use a global queue which is the same QoS as your current thread.

Bottom line, the correct way to specify the QoS is to dispatch the call to `concurrentPerform` to the desired queue, e.g.:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 3) { (i) in
        ...
    }
}
```

This is easily verified empirically by adding a break point and looking at the queue in the Xcode debugger:

[image]

---

Needless to say, the suggestion of adding the `let _ = ...` is incorrect. Consider the following:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
    let _ = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)

    DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 3) { (i) in
        ...
    }
}
```

This will run with “utility” QoS, not “user initiated”.

Again, this is easily verified empirically:

[image]

---

See WWDC 2017 video [Modernizing Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/706/?time=285) for a discussion about `DISPATCH_APPLY_AUTO` and `concurrentPerform`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I knew the code from the tutorial was probably wrong, but raywenderlich.com tutorials are usually pretty reliable.