# DispatchQueue async issue

Tags: swift, asynchronous, dispatch-queue

```
var numbers: [Int] = []
var queue = DispatchQueue(label: "myqueue", attributes: .concurrent)

DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 10) { i in
    
    queue.async() {
        print(i)
        let last = numbers.last ?? 0
        numbers.append(last + 1)
    }
}

sleep(1)
print(numbers)
```

It output:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -- (maybe different)

The work item inside the async block runs 10 times, but why there are less than 10 numbers in the array?

The second question is if I change async to sync, the numbers are still less than 10. Why is it not [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in Swift are not thread safe. What would happen when you access them concurrently is undefined. So some elements not being added, or the wrong elements being added, or your program crashing, are all possible results from running the code.

Changing to `sync` doesn't help, because you are still posting work on a *concurrent* queue, which will run them concurrently, when you post work concurrently on it using `concurrentPerform`.

What `sync` guarantees is that it returns after the work completes, so that the code after it runs after the work is done. For example, if you have an extra `print` after `sync`:

```
queue.sync {
    print(i)
    let last = numbers.last ?? 0
    numbers.append(last + 1)
}
print("Foo")
```

`Foo` is guaranteed to be printed after `numbers.append(last + 1)`.

See also [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html).

So to achieve `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`, you should post the work on a serial queue, which guarantees that the work will be executed sequentially. Alternatively, if you only have a concurrent queue, use the `.barrier` flag:

```
queue.async(flags: .barrier) {
```

Also, if what you actually meant is for `concurrentPerform` to use `queue` to do the "concurrent performing", then as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54775099/is-it-possible-to-specify-the-dispatchqueue-for-dispatchqueue-concurrentperfo) says, you should do it like this:

```
queue.async {
    DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 10) { i in
        print(i)
        someSerialQueue.async {
            let last = numbers.last ?? 0
            numbers.append(last + 1)
        }
    }
}
```